# Pass multiple parameters into WCF Web API-service

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-web-api

I'm wondering about the behind the scenes magic that's happening when you create a WCF-Web service.

In one old project I got methods that I can call from JavaScript that look like this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
IEnumerable<Result> SearchObjects(string x, int y, double z);
```

And this works when I send { "x": "something", "y": 1, "z": 1.5 } from JavaScript.

A couple of months after the creation of that webservice, I found the WCF Web API and tried to make something similar.

Difference was that I created the route in my Global.asax with the HttpServiceHostFactory()

Now when I try to call the method, I get an exception like this

**Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 
The HttpOperationHandlerFactory is unable to determine the input parameter that should be associated with the request message content for service operation 'Invoke_LoginRequest'. If the operation does not expect content in the request message use the HTTP GET method with the operation. Otherwise, ensure that one input parameter either has it's IsContentParameter property set to 'True' or is a type that is assignable to one of the following: HttpContent, ObjectContent`1, HttpRequestMessage or HttpRequestMessage`1.**

And to get it to work, I need to declare the method like this (VB.Net)

```
Public Function Invoke_LoginRequest(ByVal request As HttpRequestMessage(Of JsonValue)) As HttpResponseMessage(Of String)
```

But then I need to parse the JsonValue manually. So how does the old version really work? And is there any way I could get that behaviour back?

Best regards
Jesper

Comment: Did you find an acceptable resolution to this? I'm looking for similar but deserilizing from a URL Encoded POST Body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Define a class containing the data that you want to receive, i.e,

```
public class Model
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public double z { get; set; }
}
```

2) Define the operation parameter as an `ObjectContent<Model>`

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ObjectContent<Model> c){
    Model m = c.ReadAs();
    ...
}
```

HTH
Pedro

Comment: It's a bit better, but where did the automatic JSON-serialization go? And is there anyway I can do it myself? So I can pass parameters as in the first example.

Comment: You can insert an operation handler that receives the model as input and outputs the individual members. Then, these individual members can be operation's parameters

Comment: So you need a model-object for each method exposed to the webservice? That sounds, cumbersome... Guesss I'll try and find a way to make a custom operation handler that converts to the operation's parameters.

Comment: Yes, I also agree that it is cumbersome. An alternative would be to: 1) have a HttpRequestMessage<T> as the handler input; 2) get the content from the request as a JsonValue 3) for each operation parameter (all simple types), retrieve the value from the JsonValue

Comment: Take a look at http://github.com/pmhsfelix/WcfWebApi.Preview5.Explorations/blob/master/WcfWebApi.Preview5.Explorations.SelfHostedDemos/JsonValueDemo.cs